# Check if an element is present in 3D array Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have an array which gets instantiated in `viewDidLoad` like `var bookingsArray : [[String]] = []`

I am adding elements to it in this way:

```
var configuration: [String] = []
            configuration.append(textfieldFacility.text!)
            configuration.append((pickSlotTF.text?.components(separatedBy: " ")[0])!)
            configuration.append((pickSlotTF.text?.components(separatedBy: " ")[1])!)
            bookingsArray.append(configuration as [String])
```

`bookingsArray` looks like :

```
[["A", "20-08-2017", "14:00"], ["B", "20-08-2017", "14:00"]]
```

While adding new elements to `bookingsArray`, I want to check if the new element is already present in the array. How do I do it in this case of multi-dimensional array?

Comment: Your `bookingsArray` is a  2d array not 3D array right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, if you want unique objects use a `Set`.

If this is not possible I highly recommend to use a custom struct which can conform to `Equatable` rather than a nested array , for example

```
struct Booking : Equatable {
    let facilty : String
    let date : String
    let time : String

    static func ==(lhs : Booking, rhs : Booking) -> Bool {
        return lhs.facilty == rhs.facilty && lhs.date == rhs.date && lhs.time == rhs.time
    }
}
```

Then declare the array as

```
var bookingsArray = [Booking]()
```

and create an object with

```
let dateArray = pickSlotTF.text!.components(separatedBy: " ")
let configuration = Booking(facility: textfieldFacility.text!,
                            date: dateArray[0],
                            time = dateArray[1])
bookingsArray.append(configuration)
```

The huge benefit is that you can easily check

```
if bookingsArray.contains(item)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply search for it with [`contains()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2297359-contains).

```
var configuration: [String] = []
configuration.append(textfieldFacility.text!)
configuration.append((pickSlotTF.text?.components(separatedBy: " ")[0])!)
configuration.append((pickSlotTF.text?.components(separatedBy: " ")[1])!)

if !bookingsArray.contains(where: {$0 == configuration}) {
    bookingsArray.append(configuration)
}
```